# how can i change the size of a png file with R

Tags: r

I am plotting png files and getting a small picture.

Do you know some simple code that can change size of a png plot?

(my plots are too high and too "slim".

In addition is there a way to change resolution of the plot ?

thanks 
yigeal

Comment: What code are you using to generate the png files?  See `?png` for details of specifying height and width parameters.

Answer (score 24):

?png

```
png(filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,
    units = "px", pointsize = 12, bg = "white", res = NA,
    restoreConsole = TRUE)
```

Change `width` and `height` in pixels, set `res` in dpi, default is 72 for larger plots I generally use something around 120. You'll have to play with it to get the font to look how you want it.

Example:

```
png()
plot(rnorm(100))
dev.off()
```