# Setting the size of an R graph for a png file

Tags: php, r

I'm trying to use R to prototype a data visualization web application. My plan is to create a png file that will be inserted into the page for now. My problem is that I can't find a way to control the actual size of the graphs created by R. Here's my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div id="viz1">
            <?php
            exec('Rscript index.r');
            echo ('<img src="temp.png" />');
            unlink('temp2.png');
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my simple R script for creating a histogram:

```
png(
  filename = 'temp2.png'
  , width = 200
  , height = 200
  , units = 'px'
  , res = NA
)

hist(rnorm(100), col = 'red')
dev.off()
```

The width and height specified by the png() function doesn't change the size of the graph.

Possible duplicates, but somewhat different: [how can i change the size of a png file with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190064/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-a-png-file-with-r)

Comment: You mean the resulting image file is not 200 x 200 pixels? It is for me if you check the image file directly. Perhaps it is just not displaying at 200x200 pixels in the web page, i.e. problem on the HTML side?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Great call. I realize that I could simply stylize the img element with 200 by 200 pixels and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mathematical.coffee pointed out, I was actually asking the *wrong* question. The size of the png file is created. It is simply the size of the img element in the HTML that was causing my problem.

A quick hack fixed my problem:

```
<img src="temp2.png" style="width: 200px; height: 200px" />
```

Comment: But why is it the wrong size on the page? There must be some CSS that is styling img elements with default class and id tags. Install firebug, right-click on image, then look in the CSS rules to see where the height and width are set. What you should then do (maybe) is to give the img elements a class and set the height and width in your css rather than in the html...